# custom options on configurable products with no associated products

Tags: configurable-product, custom-options

I see in magento admin configurable products, that have no associated products custom options don't show on frontend,I set that product inventory but still nothing. I know it is possible but I am not programmer so I dont have a clue where to start and havent found any useful info on the web,any help is much appreciated.
Thx

Comment: Why dont create a simple product with custom option ?